# Is there a simple way to start splitting a string from a certain point?

Tags: python, string, line

Let's say I have this string `'This is an example hello'`

Which if split would become `['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'hello']`

If I wanted to only take the last three words and put them in a list, to get `['an', 'example', 'hello']` is there a simple way to do that?

An idea would of course be to split the whole sentence then just remove the first elements but I was wondering if there was some other method I was missing to directly get the same result. Thank you in advance.

PS: This is my first question asked here, I'm sorry if it's not perfect, please point out what might be wrong so I can improve next times! :)

Comment: you can use `rsplit()`

Comment: `rsplit(limit=3)`

Comment: `last_items = st.split()[-3:]`

Comment: Look up `splitting` for your first problem and `slicing` for the second one :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```py
string = 'This is an example hello'

split = string.split()[-3:]
```

Because we know that split string returns a list, we can get the last 3 elements of the list using `[-3:]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with its optional `maxsplit` argument. And Use `*` operator to pack it into a `list`:

```
>>> string = 'This is an example hello'
>>> first_part, *last_three = string.rsplit(sep=' ', maxsplit=3)

>>> first_part
'This is'

>>> last_three
['an', 'example', 'hello']
```